# How to load Facebook Pixel NoScript code in DNN codebehind?

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke, noscript, facebook-pixel

We have a checkout module with custom code which will show a wizard for End Users and another multi view when the user is a Dealer. I am trying to only fire the Facebook pixel code when the user is an End User. The problem I am having is the NoScript code which I can't call in a JavaScript function. I also don't want to put it after the script tags in the ASCX file because the rest of the pixel code is only called when an invoice is generated and the Facebook Pixel Helper Browser Extension is giving an error because of this. I attempted to split the Script and NoScript code. In the codebehind below I am setting the Facebook Pixel ID from a module setting which I have set. I have also created a setting for the NoScript code which is the FacebookPixelForEndUserNoScriptImageCode setting.

[image]

```
if (Settings["FacebookPixelIDForEndUser"] != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Settings["FacebookPixelIDForEndUser"].ToString())){
      EndUserFirstName = SessionManager.CurrentUserInfo.FirstName;
      EndUserLastName = SessionManager.CurrentUserInfo.LastName;
      EndUserEmail = SessionManager.CurrentUserInfo.PersonalEmailAddress;

      facebookInitializationCodeID = Settings["FacebookPixelIDForEndUser"].ToString();
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "attacheEvents", "javascript:initializeFacebookPixelCodeForEndUser();", true);

      string FacebookPixelNoScriptCode = Settings["FacebookPixelForEndUserNoScriptImageCode"].ToString();
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "FacebookPixelForEndUserNoScriptImageCode", FacebookPixelNoScriptCode, false);
}
```

The code below is the front end code which is called from the codebehind.

```
    function initializeFacebookPixelCodeForEndUser(){
    var custemail = '<%=EndUserEmail%>';
    var custfirstname = '<%=EndUserFirstName%>';
    var custlastname = '<%=EndUserLastName%>';

    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
    {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
        if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
        n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
        t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', '<%=facebookInitializationCodeID%>', {
        em: custemail,
        fn: custfirstname,
        ln: custlastname,
    });
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
}
```

This is the NoScript code which I set in the settings and call right after the RegisterStartupScript code has been called.

```
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr? 
id=RemovedTheIDForPrivacy&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

My current code seems to be failing as it is saying that fbq is undefined. I am calling the Purchase Event right after the above code has been called, but I think it is failing because the code is not together.

```
<script>
 fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
   value: 1,
   currency: 'ZAR',
 });
</script>
```

Are there any solution on how to call the Script and NoScript code within Javascript / JQuery?

Comment: Where/when is it determined whether the user is such an end user, or a dealer? Unless that has to happen client-side on the same page, your server-side logic should handle this, and either output the JS code for the tracking, or not ...

Comment: The code above is actually within an IF statement which determines if it is an End User, thus it is handled on the server-side. (I did not include it in this question). The problem is that I want to call the Pixel Tracking code from the codebehind and set the variables. Is there a programmatic way I can build and execute the Pixel Tracking Code?

Comment: I don’t understand what you are asking. Where is the actual problem to either output or not output a working piece of code, based on a condition?

Comment: My problem is that I am trying to set the Advanced Matching variables on the client-side after I have called it from the server-side, but I can't include the <noscript> tag within a JavaScript function. I tried to split the <script> and <noscript> code, but when I register a purchase it can't fire as it says that fbq is not defined. So my question is, how can I build the Facebook Pixel Code in the Codebehind in C#?   fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
    value: 1,
    currency: 'ZAR',
  });
</script>

Comment: Are you referring to the client-side JS variables `custemail`, `custfirstname` and `custlastname`? I don’t see how that justifies your “taking apart” of the code to begin with.

Comment: The Facebook Pixel Code is on the client-side, but it can only be triggered when an End User Invoice has been generated. The problem is I am trying to fetch this code from the codebehind with this code, but it wont work as you cant put this code with a noscript tag inside a JavaScript function. ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "attacheEvents", "javascript:initializeFacebookPixelCodeForEndUser();", true);

Comment: Well then leave out the noscript part ...? If you are loading this via client-side scripting to begin with, then the fallback for the case that client-side scripting wasn’t available can hardly be needed anyways.

Comment: The Pixel code requires the noscript part as the img tag within this code returns an HTTP Get request. I think somehow this code is executed anyway. I tested my code without the noscript part and the Pixel helper plugin on my browser is showing a red warning. I will have to build it with a StringWriter in the codebehind. Thanks for the help so far. I will let you know if I came right.

Comment: That’s nonsense, the noscript part is only there to send some tracking information when JavaScript is _not_ available. When JS is available, it is completely ignored anyway (because that’s what a `noscript` element _does_.)

Comment: It could be that the Facebook Pixel Helper extension I am using for Google Chrome is looking for both scripts and therefore is failing when I remove the noscript section. I also found this interesting article when using Google Tag Manager and the Facebook Pixel Tracking Code: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/facebook-pixel-noscript/

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you have an error about fbq not initialized it is due to the code that you are rendering triggering before the actual Facebook script is called, thus it is not defined yet.

I would ensure that the reference to the Facebook JS is before your code (for example at the top of the skin, or header, rather than the footer.)

As for the no script, if you want to load it from the code behind you can use an `<asp:literal>` control to render it to the page if you are using the WebForms pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by writing the Facebook Pixel Tracking code on the server-side using StringWriter.

```
if (!SessionManager.CurrentUserInfo.IsCustomerDealer)
                {     

                    if (Settings["FacebookPixelIDForEndUser"] != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Settings["FacebookPixelIDForEndUser"].ToString()))
                    {
                        EndUserFirstName = SessionManager.CurrentUserInfo.FirstName;
                        EndUserLastName = SessionManager.CurrentUserInfo.LastName;
                        EndUserEmail = SessionManager.CurrentUserInfo.UserName;

                        facebookInitializationCodeID = Settings["FacebookPixelIDForEndUser"].ToString();

                        string FacebookPixelResult = string.Empty;

                        using (var FBPxl = new StringWriter())
                        using (var FBCodescript = new HtmlTextWriter(FBPxl))
                        {
                            FBCodescript.AddAttribute(Attr.Type, "text/javascript");
                            FBCodescript.RenderBeginTag(Tag.Script);
                            //load ecommerce plugin
                            FBCodescript.WriteLine("!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function(){n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};");
                            FBCodescript.WriteLine("if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n; n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0';");
                            FBCodescript.WriteLine("n.queue =[]; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;");
                            FBCodescript.WriteLine("t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];");
                            FBCodescript.WriteLine("s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)}");
                            FBCodescript.WriteLine("(window, document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');");
                            FBCodescript.WriteLine($"fbq('init', '{facebookInitializationCodeID}', {{ em: '{EndUserEmail}', fn: '{EndUserFirstName}', ln: '{EndUserLastName}',}});");
                            FBCodescript.WriteLine("fbq('track', 'PageView');");
                            FBCodescript.RenderEndTag();
                            FBCodescript.WriteLine($"<noscript><img height='1' width='1' style='display:none'  src='https://www.facebook.com/tr?id={facebookInitializationCodeID}&ev=PageView&noscript=1'/></noscript>");
                            FacebookPixelResult = FBCodescript.InnerWriter.ToString();
                        }

                        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myFacebookPixelInitialization", FacebookPixelResult ,false);

                    }
                }
```