# Calling Facebook Pixel Code with the <noscript> programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, dotnetnuke, noscript

How can I call the Facebook Pixel Code with the **noscript** programmatically?
The Facebook Pixel Helper extension seems to break when you separate the **script** and **noscript** code. Is there a way to wrap a function around the **script** and **noscript** code or a way to build it in the codebehind in DotNetNuke?

The reason why I want to call this code programmatically from codebehind is so that I can set the ID and Advanced Matching / variables (custemail, custfirstname and custlastname)

I have a similair question about this with more code of what I am trying to do but though this post would be simpler to understand. 
[How to load Facebook Pixel NoScript code in DNN codebehind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654538/how-to-load-facebook-pixel-noscript-code-in-dnn-codebehind)

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
 !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
 {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
 n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
 if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
 n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
 t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
 s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
 fbq('init', '1564120846976681', {
 em: custemail,
 fn: custfirstname,
 ln: custlastname,
 });
 fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
 src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=00000000000&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/> 
</noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The `img` tag performs a simple HTTP GET on the provided URL.
You should be able to do the same in C# code.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the function of the img tag. We have one page with a DotNetNuke module with Multiviews. I can only call the Facebook Pixel Code once an Order is generated on the Checkout page. We have End Users and Dealers so the Multiview will be different on the Checkout page. I already have server-side code to determine if the logged in user is an End User. Currently I only want to track them with the Facebook Pixel Code. There is no "Thank you" page as this is also handled on the same page. The URL http://dnndev.me/Checkout will get this string ?OrderNo=1340319 when completed.